# Why to reference the this variable to modify the DOM elements? :Clarification on 'this' in Vue Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scope, this

I have a vue component with following structure:

```
   export default{
     name: '',
     data: function () {
        return {
           var1 :{},
           var2 : {},
           ...
        }
     },
     created: function () {
         this.methodName1()
     },
     methods: {
        methodName2: function () {
           var context = this

           rp(options).then(function () {
              context.methodName1()
              return null
           }).catch(function (err) {
              console.log(err)
           })
       },
       methodName1: function () {
             //function body
       }
   }
```

My doubt is why `this.methodName1` gives undefined where as

```
    var context = this; 
    context.methodName1
```

works perfectly fine inside the methodName2?

Why do we need to reference the `this` variable especially to modify the DOM elements?

Comment: is your question why you can not write `this.methodName1()` in `then` callback in methodName2?

Comment: Yes, not only in callback outside callback too

Comment: VueJS holds your hand for `methods`, rewiring their `this` into more sophisticated object. But it doesn't do this for code inside the methods. You'd use fat arrow functions - or store context explicitly, as you did in that snippet.

Comment: Ok. I understood a bit but my confusion still lies at 
1. why are we storing reference to this in another variable? 
2. why direct use of this doesn't work? (`var context = this; 
    context.methodName1`  isn't it same as using `this.methodName1()`)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look closely at the [Lifecycle-Diagram](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram) in official docs. You're trying to run `this.methodName1()` in `created` which is hooked before your `methods`, meaning you're trying to run a method that has not been attached yet.
`mounted` is where all your methods are already available.
Change:

```
created: function () {
     this.methodName1()
},
```

to

```
mounted: function () {
     this.methodName1()
},
```

and you should be good to go.

Comment: `created` hook is ok for accessing methods and component data, `mounted` is neccessary if you want to access DOM or manipulate child components. Your answer is incorrect.